# Stop Kinesis Firehose delivery to redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have this kinesis firehose delivery stream to s3 and redshift. While I want to continue putting the data to s3 but I want to temporarily stop sending data to redshift. One trick is to change the database table name. But that is not very sophisticated as request is still being made. I was wondering if there is any other way to stop sending data to redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there is. I've usually resorted to renaming the table, like you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using AWS CLI update-destination command:
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/firehose/update-destination.html

Command example:

```
aws firehose update-destination 
 --delivery-stream-name "name" 
 --current-delivery-stream-version-id "1" 
 --destination-id "id" 
 --extended-s3-destination-update '
{
"RoleARN":"ROLE",
"BucketARN":"BUKCET",
"Prefix":"PREFIX","BufferingHints":{"SizeInMBs":1,"IntervalInSeconds":60},
"CompressionFormat":"UNCOMPRESSED",
"EncryptionConfiguration":{"NoEncryptionConfig":"NoEncryption"},
"CloudWatchLoggingOptions":{"Enabled":true,"LogGroupName":"LOG_NAME","LogStreamName":"STREAM_NAME"}
}'
```